# Meaning of natural action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

What is the meaning of the assertion :'the group $G$ acts in a natural way on the set $S$'?
I don't understand the meaning of 'natural'.

thanks!

Comment: It just means "natural" - it is an aesthetic term, not a mathematical one.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19644/what-is-the-definition-of-canonical

Comment: @Martin I think "canonical" is stronger than "natural". Although I cannot think of any easy examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means "natural" - it is an aesthetic term, not a mathematical one.

For example, $S_3$ acts on the set $\{1,2,3\}$ in a natural way, while if $N$ is a characteristic subgroup of a group $G$ then $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ acts on $G/N$ in a natural way.

Comment: So $G$=SL(3,2) acts in a natural way on $\{1,...,7\}$ because there is a transitive action on the seven point of the proiective plane on ${F}_2$, is it right?  thanks!

Comment: Yeah - just label the seven points.

Comment: "The" action of $S_3$ on $\{1,2,3\}$ is natural (or canonical) because it is this action that is used as the very definition of the group. $SL(3,2)$ acts canonically (namely, by definition) on $\mathbb F_2^3$ and hence also on the projective plane; but without a natural/canonical way to enumerate the seven points of the projective plane we don't get a natural action on $\{1,\ldots,7\}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Sometimes I wish I could upvote comments multiple times.

Comment: @Hagen I disagree that without the ordering we don't get a *natural* action. I agree that it isn't canonical, but I feel that this is the difference between *natural* and *canonical*. For example, $S_3$ acts on any set with three elements in a natural way, and this way is unique up to automorphism. But without further information, the action is not canonical. That said, that is based on the definition of "natural" which I use, which cannot be standard because it is a non-technical word but I believe that this definition is the most...natural...